# How to get certain phrase from the middle of the string in Python

Tags: python

I have silly question - How can I get just the middle bunch of words? I'm missing with one value.

```
string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
start = string.index("content")
print(string[start:i'm stucked here!!!])
```

Any ideas how to count this value to delete the things after content?

Comment: Which things after content do you wish to delete?

Comment: You need to add clarification to your problem. What do you want actually?

Comment: I want just to get "content" from this string using this syntax - string[start:end]

Comment: string[start] ??

Comment: If, like in your example, you know the word in advance, then it is as easy as `end = start + len(word)`, then `string[start:end]` will give you the word only.

Comment: You need to use the syntax mentioned by @kikucik89.  You know the start position of "content" (12) so just add its the length `len(content)` to it. `string[:12+7]`

Comment: Once again. I need to get "content" for string. My goal is to delete everything what exists behind "content" so I can print only this word "content"

Comment: Ok, got it :) string[start:start+len("content")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `string[start:end]` return the sub-sequence of string from index `start` to `end` (not included).

If you want to extract a word that start at the position `start` and that word is of length `n`, then the `string[start:(start+n)]` will return the word.

To get the length of a word, use `len(word)`.

That gives you:

```
string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
word = "content"
start = string.index(word)
end = start + len(word)
print(string[start:end])
```

Answer (score 1):

For the specific use case you can use the below code

```
string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
start = string.index("content") + len("content")
string = string [:start]
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.search(searchItem)` will return the start index of the term you are looking for and -1 if it doesn't exist.

So in your case,

string.search("content") will give you 12, which is the index of 'c' in content;

so,

```
start = string.search("content") + len("content") //len to add the search term as well

//and to get substring:

string = string.substr(0,start);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
word = "content"
start = string.index(word)

print(string[start:start+len(word)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely knowing how versatile you need this to be, or the full purpose of its use, here are a few options.

You could take the string and convert it to a list. This would give you more iteration options, depending on what your needs would be:

```
string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
_string = string.split()
print(_string)

output = ['Here', 'is', 'the', 'content', 'and', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'get', 'middle', 'words']
```

If you wanted a method where you could change the word you're searching for and it would not throw an exception if the word wasn't in the phrase, here's a possibility. It may look a little verbose but again, not knowing what application you'd be using it for, the 'safety nets' it has could be helpful:

```
_string = "Here is the content and I want to get middle words"
word_find = "content"

def get_word_indicies(input_string, word_find):
    start_index = None
    end_index = None

    for i, x in enumerate(input_string):
        if x in word_find:
            if start_index is None:
                start_index = I
            else:
                end_index = i + 1
                if (end_index - start_index) == len(word_find):
                    return [start_index, end_index]
        else:
            start_index = None
            end_index = None
    start_index = None
    end_index = None
    return [start_index,end_index]

x, y = get_word_indicies(_string, word_find)
print(_string[x:y])
```